# Getting C++ Function Address using VSCode & VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, function-pointers

I've tried this piece of code in my VSCode, and theoretically the output should give me the function's address

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int getNumber(){
    return 9000;
}

int main(){
    cout<<getNumber<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Once I run the code in VSCode, the output is: 1

So I asked my friend to run the exact same code on Visual Studio (since I don't have VS), and the output is a memory address.

My question is,

1. Why is the output of that code is different when run in VSCode and VS?
2. What should I do to be able to get the function's address in VSCode using that exact same code?

Comment: `VSCode` is an IDE. How do you compile / run that code?

Comment: @user4581301 OP appears to already know that.

Comment: Yeah. Re-read the question.

Comment: I'm sorry if I get the question wrong. I'm using minGW as compiler, and I run the code in terminal

Comment: Nothing wrong here. You've tripped over a wacky case where you don't get the conversion most people would expect. This is hard to search for unless you already know what happened, and why ask the question if you know what happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::ostream::operator<<` has an overload for `bool` and a pointer can be implicitly converted to a `bool`, so the output from VSCode (where you tell us you are compiling with mingw) is correct.  Since the address of function `getNumber` is bound to be non-zero, this becomes `true`, which equals `1`, when converted to a `bool`, so that's what gets printed.

On the other hand, MSVC (which is what Visual Studio uses to compile your code) appears to be getting it wrong.

To be sure that you output the address of the function, you can do:

```
cout << (void *) getNumber << endl;
```

Again, a specific overload for `void *` ensures that `getNumber` is then interpreted as an address.

---

**Addendum:** With a sufficiently high warning level set, gcc will warn you about this, see: https://wandbox.org/permlink/J9kxSzLshRQsdt0e

Comment: A quick hack trick to see if you're really getting a `bool` when you don't want to is slap `<< boolalpha` into that print line and see if you get true instead.

Comment: @user4581301 Good idea.

Comment: That is some obscure warning! `warning: the address of 'int getNumber()' will never be NULL [-Waddress]`

Comment: @VladFeinstein Yes, I agree, but at least it raises a flag.  clang does slightly better: https://wandbox.org/permlink/PdLdfUGaeEsPsG30

Comment: Thankyou, your answer and this discussion has cleared my confusion :D

Comment: VSCode might behave differently.

You can try: `cout<< &getNumber <<endl;`

This should cout the address of the function